# Create Bootstrap tab link

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I have a tab list, like the following:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="info_generali-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#info_generali" role="tab" aria-controls="info_generali" aria-selected="true">Informazioni principali </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="moduli_lavorazione-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#moduli_lavorazione" role="tab" aria-controls="moduli_lavorazione" aria-selected="false">Moduli Lavorazione</a>
            </li>
```

Actually, if I click on a single tab, the url does not change. But If, ad example, I want to redirect the second tab (when click on) to the following link: `/prova_uno` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your existing code will not change address, it will show a named anchor "#info_generali" or "#moduli_lavorazione".

If you want one of those tabs to not switch to a tab but instead load a new page then remove the data-toggle and set the target href to the page you wish to open:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="info_generali-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#info_generali" role="tab" aria-controls="info_generali" aria-selected="true">Informazioni principali </a>
    </li>  <!-- This one will display the tab-->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="moduli_lavorazione-tab" href="/prova_uno" role="tab" aria-controls="moduli_lavorazione" aria-selected="false">Moduli Lavorazione</a>
    </li> <!-- This one will navigate to URL /prova_uno -->
</ul>
```

So to recap, to make one of your tab formatted navigation links open a new page instead of display a tab:

- Remove the data-toggle
- Set the URL in href